# How to find the number of child for a parent in Androidviewclient

Tags: android, monkeyrunner, androidviewclient

I am trying to automate the Bluetooth test cases. 
After scanning, i wanted to get the list and count of Available and paired devices. Further check weather my ref device name exist in DUT list. 
Is there any way through which i can display and traverse the hierarchy of anyone parent( available and pared devices) and with only text option(since most of the inbuilt traverse option with Class ID , no_id, Test etc). 
If i want to run a loop to search Ref device in DUT, how that is possible through Androidviewclient 3.2 and monkeyrunner.

Comment: Why don't you use latest `AndroidViewClient` version and what is Android device API level?

Comment: We have written multiple testcases with monkey-runner and since monkey-runner works in coordinates bases. So we are doing minimal changes using Androidviewclient.Latest version of androidviewclient does not support Monkey-runner

Answer (score 1):

You can easily find the number of children of any View

```
# class=android.widget.ListView
android___id_list = vc.findViewByIdOrRaise("android:id/list")
print "list has", len(android___id_list.children), "children"
```

This is **Wireless & networks** settings on a **KitKat** phone.